# How to give GUI to remote server and access it from my local machine in ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, remote-server, ubuntu-server

I have one ubuntu server located in one city(remotely), i want to give dummy display/GUI to that server and access it from my local ubuntu machine, how can i create this, please suggest me if there is any way to create a dummy display to that server from my local machine and can i access it like my own local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect via ssh to your Linux server and do the following in cli:

sudo passwd root (put password for your username that you want to connect from)

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop (to install your GUI)

sudo apt-get install xrdp (to install the middleware to connect through)

open port on your cloud/host portal for remote connection (port 3389)

Do your remote desktop to your vm dns using that port and use ur created username/password to go through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ssh service, open a terminal and write

```
# sudo root ssh@ip_address_of_server
```

so if the ip address of server is : 192.168.1.22
the command line will be :

```
# sudo root ssh@192.168.1.22
```

You do not forget to install ssh service